# Specifying a model in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

I am trying to fit a GLMM:

logit$[P(Y_{ij}=1)] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{ij} + \beta_2R_i + \gamma_i$ where $\gamma_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2_\gamma)$, $j=0,1$ and $i=0,1,...,94$.

I first went with the lme4 package in R:

```
m <-  glmer(PHENO==2 ~ GENO + RACE + (1|GROUP), family="binomial",data=iih_data,nAGQ=1 )
```

but this uses the Wald z-test by default for hypothesis test for $\beta_1=0$ which is probably not applicable in this case. It was suggested here http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq to use either MCMC or parametric bootstrap to obtain more valid p-values. I rolled my own bootstrap procedure, but it was rather slow.

So I wanted to see if MCMC method would be faster. This led me to the R package MCMCglmm. However, this package is above my understanding of statistics and I was unable to follow the examples on how to set up this analysis using MCMCglmm.

Can you help me set up the above analysis using MCMCglmm to obtain a valid p-value for $\beta_1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
library(MCMCglmm)
m <-  MCMCglmm(cbind(PHENO==2,PHENO!=2)~GENO + RACE, 
random=~GROUP ,family='multinomial2',data=iih_data,nitt=40000,thin=20)
```

Afterwards, you should check to make sure assumptions of low autocorrelation between intervals are met, and that the chain has converged, using something like:

```
plot(m)
autocorr(m$Sol)
```

There are some examples also given in the MCMCglmm vignette:

```
vignette('Overview',package='MCMCglmm')
```